# How does list.sort() work with overloaded operators?

Tags: python, oop

Code here:

```
class WeirdSortee:
    def __init__(self, string, number, sort_num):
        self.string = string
        self.number = number
        self.sort_num = sort_num
    def __lt__(self, object):
        if self.sort_num:
            return self.number < object.number
        return self.string < object.string
    def __repr__(self):
        return"{}:{}".format(self.string, self.number)

a = WeirdSortee('a', 4, True)
b = WeirdSortee('b', 3, True)
c = WeirdSortee('c', 2, True)
d = WeirdSortee('d', 1, True)
l = [a,b,c,d]
l.sort() #returns [d:1, c:2, b:3, a:4]
for i in l:
    i.sort_num = False
l.sort()
print(l) #returns [a:4, b:3, c:2, d:1]
```

I know that a < b < c < d but how does sort work with self and object? What is the object and self in this case?

Comment: `a < b` -> `a.__lt__(b)`

Comment: I guess my confusion is coming from that I don't know how sort works internally. So does sort() call a.__lt__(b), then a.__lt__(c), and so on for all items in the list?

Comment: You needn't to know, you just need to understand it use `__lt__` to decide which one is bigger.

Comment: `.sort()` compares two items at a time, always using `<`. It uses more than one algorithm depending on the data, so you can't predict *which* items will get compared ahead of time. But it will compare and swap items as necessary until the list is sorted.

Comment: Take a look at some of [these](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Python) implementations. Not saying they are the best  or even the exact same algorithm python uses internally (timsort) but should give you an idea of where the comparisons are made in the algorithm.